# How to choose automatiquely parameter choice when I run periodically The JENKINS Job

Tags: selenium, jenkins

In My Job Jenkins I have parameter "browser" type choice, where I have as values: (Chrome, Firefox) When I want to run job, I have an option select parameter. But me, I need when I am running job periodically and automatically at day to run firstly with chrome automatically and secondly with Firefox .

**Goal:** 
Jenkins should be able to choose for example, at 9H the parameter browser="chrome" and at 9h30 browser="Firefox" without any human intervention

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to create an upstream job to start it with the desired parameters.

```
stage('Starting Chrome'){
    build <jobname>, parameters: [choice(name: "browser", value: "chrome")]
}

stage('Starting Firefox'){
    build <jobname>, ...
}
```

This job can be triggered once at the desired time and will then start the other one with the right browser.

Also note that if you only want to run it with one specific parameter (e.g. only with Chrome) you could use the default parameter (the first of the choice list)

Comment: Thats how I set up my systems as well. I have a common pipeline called runner and various starters, which have different parameter sets and start times.